# jQuery Validate - Remeber the milk signup form example, where is server-side code?

Tags: php, jquery-validate

I'm trying to recreate the [Remember the Milk Signup form](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/) validation example (from [JQuery Validate plugin wiki](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#The_Remember_The_Milk_sign-up_form)). Especifically for username remote validation. If you check the example, you'll see two links at the bottom, one for client-side and the other for server-side code. The second one is not working (In all three browsers I've tried with).

So, please, does anyone have this server-side code, a link to it, or any compatible alternative that works with the client-side code provided?

P.D. I'm trying to follow stackoverflow rules with this question. If its not valid, please give me some advise.

**NOTE:** Got it working thanks to @Marc B answer, I didn't know how to pass the data between the form and the checkusername.php, I do know.

What I was using at first (Not working):
JS rules:

```
(...)
$('form').find('.classNewUsernameField').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        remote: "checkusername.php",
        minlength: minLengthField,
        messages: {
            required: "Required field!",
            remote: "Taken!",
            minlength: "Too short"
        }
        });
});
```

Server-side:

```
if (!mssql_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "pass"))
    exit ("->FAILED");

if (!mssql_select_db("db_rrhh"))
    exit ("FAILED DB");

$query = "SELECT username_user FROM table_users WHERE username_user=".$_POST['username'];
$res = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $output = true;
} else {
    $output = false;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: The demos are great for learning but they're not perfect.  Construct your own code [following the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) instead and come here when you get stuck.

Comment: Updated my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the server-side code (how to fetch: view demo page source, see that it's fetching a .phps file, hit url manually, download file, load into notepad, cut& paste here)

```
<?php
$request = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['value']));
$users = array('asdf', 'Peter', 'Peter2', 'George');
$valid = 'true';
foreach($users as $user) {
    if( strtolower($user) == $request )
        $valid = 'false';
}
echo $valid;
?>
```

pretty silly code overall.

Comment: Agreed. It doesn't serve any purpose. I am not sure it can be call as validation (in practical sense).

Comment: It may not be some great code, but it helped me to understand how to pass data between the form and checkusername.php, now I can use my sql validation and return the result it via php echo. Thank you very much.